# Dynamically set Sanic log level in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

I have exposed a route in my Sanic app to set the log-level based on the client call. E.g.

```
from sanic.log import logger, logging

@route("/main")
async def sanic_main(request):
    logger.info("Info mesg")
    logger.debug("Debug mesg")

    return json("processed")

@route("/setlevel")
async def setlevel(request):
    level = request.json["level"]
    if level == "info":
         loglevel = logging.INFO
    elif level == "debug":
         loglevel = logging.DEBUG
    logger.setLevel(loglevel)

    return json("done")
```

On setting log levels between DEBUG and INFO, however, I am observing flaky behavior where the DEBUG messages (from "/main") get printed only some times and vice versa.

NOTE: I am running multiple Sanic workers

How should I go about dynamically setting the log level?

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution for this task would be a [built-in filtering feature in Python's logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information).

Answer (score 1):

I have never done anything like this, but the `sanic.log.logger` is just an instance of `<class 'logging.Logger'>`. So, using `setLevel` should be fine.

The question is how are you running your app, and how many workers are you using? If you are in a situation where you have multiple processes, then using `/setlevel` would only change the logger for that one process.

Comment: I do have multiple (4) workers. How do I go about making the log level sync-ed across all workers?

Comment: That is definitely the problem then. I think there are so many potential ways to do it, that the question becomes very broad-scoped for SO. Post your question on the Sanic forums, and I can try and help you troubleshoot it there in a more conversant format: https://community.sanicframework.org/

Comment: Will do. Btw your comment made me think if storing the log-level outside the app (in Redis) would make sense. That way, when a client invokes a route, a decorator can go check and set the log-level before serving every request. What do you think? My only concern would be the added latency but with Redis, I don't expect this to be a big deal.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760808/dynamically-set-sanic-log-level-in-python/59764944#59764944

@sandyp will respond in the thread

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using `aioredis` as captured in the blog here:

https://medium.com/@sandeepvaday/route-triggered-state-update-across-python-sanic-workers-a0f7ab0f6e4